# What increases Histamine in the body?

Tags: medications, antihistamines

What increases histamine in the human body, and are there oral forms of intake to stimulate this increase?

Comment: What referenced health benefits are you proposing?

Comment: What has your previous research revealed? Consuming histamines is different from increasing "your levels". And like already pointed at: why,  or what for? Please take the [tour] read the [help] and [edit] the question with the help of [ask].

Comment: I've reworded the question to be more concise, although the purpose of the question remains questionable.

Answer (score 4):

Yep. Try spoiled fish.

> **Histamine Poisoning (Scombroid Fish Poisoning): An Allergy-Like Intoxication**
>
> Histamine poisoning results from the consumption of foods, typically
>   certain types of fish and cheeses, that contain unusually high levels
>   of histamine. Spoiled fish of the families, Scombridae and
>   Scomberesocidae (e.g. tuna, mackerel, bonito), are commonly implicated
>   in incidents of histamine poisoning, which leads to the common usage
>   of the term, “scombroid fish poisoning”, to describe this illness.
>   However, certain non-scombroid fish, most notably mahi-mahi, bluefish,
>   and sardines, when spoiled are also commonly implicated in histamine
>   poisoning. Also, on rare occasions, cheeses especially Swiss cheese,
>   can be implicated in histamine poisoning.
>
> **The symptoms of histamine poisoning generally resemble the symptoms
>   encountered with IgE-mediated food allergies. The symptoms include
>   nausea, vomiting, diarrhea, an oral burning sensation or peppery
>   taste, hives, itching, red rash, and hypotension.** The onset of the
>   symptoms usually occurs within a few minutes after ingestion of the
>   implicated food, and the duration of symptoms ranges from a few hours
>   to 24 h. Antihistamines can be used effectively to treat this
>   intoxication.
>
> Histamine is formed in foods by certain bacteria that are able to
>   decarboxylate the amino acid, histidine. However, foods containing
>   unusually high levels of histamine may not appear to be outwardly
>   spoiled. Foods with histamine concentrations exceeding 50 mg per 100 g
>   of food are generally considered to be hazardous. Histamine formation
>   in fish can be prevented by proper handling and refrigerated storage
>   while the control of histamine formation in cheese seems dependent on
>   insuring that histamine-producing bacteria are not present in
>   significant numbers in the raw milk.

Lehane, L. & Olley, J. (2000). Histamine fish poisoning revisited. *International Journal of Food Microbiology*, *58*, 1-37.